Issue with setting the values for tf_estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver
My TFX model is implemented using a custom tf.estimator.EstimatorV2 class. I'm trying to export the model so that it accepts individual features (extracted from a serialized tf.Example) as inputs, rather than the default single serialized string.
To achieve this, I'm defining a tf_estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver using the following code:
  def parsing_transforming_serving_input_fn():
    """Serving input_fn that applies transforms to raw data in tf.Examples."""
    raw_input_fn = tf_estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(
        feature_spec, default_batch_size=None)
    serving_input_receiver = raw_input_fn()
    transformed_features = tf_transform_output.transform_raw_features(
        serving_input_receiver.features, drop_unused_features=True)

    def _parse_function(serialized_example):
      # Parse the input tf.Example proto using the feature schema
      input_features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, feature_spec)
      return input_features

    # Define a placeholder for the serialized tf.Example
    serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(
        dtype=tf.string,
        shape=[None],
        name='input_example_tensor',
    )

    def get_tensor_spec(feature_spec):
      tensor_spec_dict = {}
      for key, feature in feature_spec.items():
        if isinstance(feature, tf.FixedLenFeature):
          tensor_spec_dict[key] = tf.TensorSpec(
              shape=feature.shape, dtype=feature.dtype
          )
        elif isinstance(feature, tf.VarLenFeature):
          tensor_spec_dict[key] = tf.SparseTensorSpec(
              shape=None, dtype=feature.dtype
          )
        else:
          raise ValueError(f'Unsupported feature type: {type(feature)}')
      return tensor_spec_dict

    dtype_dict = get_tensor_spec(feature_spec)

    # Parse the serialized tf.Example

    input_features = tf.map_fn(
        _parse_function, serialized_tf_example, dtype=dtype_dict
    )

    # Create placeholders for each individual feature
    receiver_tensors = {}
    for feature_name, feature_tensor in input_features.items():
      if isinstance(feature_tensor, tf.SparseTensor):
        receiver_tensors[feature_name] = tf.sparse_placeholder(
            dtype=feature_tensor.dtype, name=feature_name
        )
      else:
        receiver_tensors[feature_name] = tf.placeholder(
            dtype=feature_tensor.dtype,
            shape=feature_tensor.shape,
            name=feature_name,
        )

    return tf_estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(
        transformed_features, receiver_tensors
    )

However, while this code doesn't produce any runtime errors, the exported model lacks signature values when loaded. This suggests that the ServingInputReceiver inputs might be incorrectly configured.
Any insights into what I might be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
